# RVM Change from Mixed-Mode to Multiple-Users Mode

Tags: ruby, rvm, passenger

While trying to get a new Sinatra app up and running, I unwisely followed one of the steps on the Phusion Passenger error page which recommended enabling RVM mixed mode with rvm user gemsets.

I gave it a try just to see if it would help me get anywhere, but now I very much regret doing it as I am further than I was before from solving my problem. Before my gems were saving to /usr/local which was perfect except for the weird problem of passenger not finding the correct wrapper.

How can I undo mixed-mode and go back to multiple-users mode? The only instructions I can find online are for moving TO mixed mode, not how to disable it!

Comment: One of the biggest problems with the internet is *NOTHING EVER GETS FLUSHED* even though it should be. In a recent conversation with the folks on the RVM IRC channel, I was told that mixed and multi-user modes are to be avoided *UNLESS* you're a *very* experienced sysadmin, capable of working through the problems encountered. I am fairly experienced but I don't want to be come more experienced, so I converted our multi-user configuration development host back to single user, at their recommendation, for simplicity and ease of use.

Comment: If I remember right, to disable, delete the /usr/local/rvm directory and any entries in /etc/bash.bashrc.

Comment: I'm afraid that single user isn't a great option for me, because on this server there are multiple users updating the apps and on our production server I have to maintain rails / sinatra apps without sudo access (it's maddening).  So unfortunately although I'm not an experience sysadmin I have to do what I can.
I'm a bit reluctant to remove the /usr/local/rvm directory, as that is where my passenger gem is living, among other things, but if I get desperate I may try that, thanks.

Comment: I believe that `rvm user none` has done the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rvm user none`

I should have tried checking the command line documentation first, rather than hunting fruitlessly around the rvm online docs and elsewhere on google.  I took a guess at "none" and it paid off.

```
$ rvm user
Usage: rvm user [[gemsets] [rubies] [hooks] [pkgs] [wrappers] [all] [--skel]|none]
```